# How can I access request information from within the serialization process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a (self-hosted) WebApi application using Visual Studio 2012 targetting .Net 4+ and with an eye on moving to VS2013 as soon as possible to take advantage of MVC 5 and WebApi 2.0.

I need to prefix all outgoing Uri's with a string that is sent as a query parameter on the incoming request. The challenge is to do this without any specific code in controllers, models or views/viewmodels. And if at all possible, I would also like to stay away from using an action filter that would need to use reflection/recursion to work through all properties of the outgoing response, though it would be fine to use a result action filter to make the url prefix available to the serializer.

What I have come with so far is a `DelegatingHandler` to get the url prefix to use from the request's query parameters so it can be added as a property to some request/controller context object; and with a `JsonConverter` to add the desired prefix to all `Uri` type properties in responses.

**What I am left with is getting the Url prefix specified in the request's parameters to the convertor.** The serializer that is passed to the `JsonConvertor` does have a `Context` property, but I can't see if and how that is related to the request context.

I can think of a number of approaches to solve this, but keep run into "lack of knowledge" walls on how MVC/WebApi carries request (context) information around the pipeline.

**Delegating Handler:**

```cs
class UrlPrefixHandler : DelegatingHandler 
{
    private string GetUrlPrefixValue(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var queryStrings = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
        if (queryStrings == null)
            return null;

        var match = queryStrings.FirstOrDefault(kv => string.Compare(kv.Key, "url_prefix", true) == 0);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
            return null;

        return match.Value;
    }

    async protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string urlPrefix = GetUrlPrefixValue(request);

        // TODO : How do I get this to the serializer on a per request basis?
        //        and do this without placing requirements on controllers/models/views?

        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Json Converter:**

```cs
class UriPrefixConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Uri).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject result = new JObject();

        //serializer.

        Uri u = (Uri)value as Uri;

        // TODO : Getting the prefix from the request's context somehow
        Uri prefixed = new Uri("/uriPrefix" + u.OriginalString, UriKind.Relative);

        writer.WriteValue(prefixed.OriginalString);
    }
```